# Is it possible to parse rich snippets on Google Search API? JSON

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-api

I'm trying to scrape a country from linkedin profile that's displayed on google results.
[image: Rich snippet as displayed on google search]

When I try to get info that's on this search results snippet through the following code:
All I get is the 'description' of this search result and not the grey part;
`var country=JSON.parse(response).items[0].snippet`

Comment: If your response is HTML then JSON.parse() does not create a valid object.  You might try using XML but more often than not it does not work if HTML is malformed.  So then you are left with trying to use regex.

Comment: Personally if I want something like this I use Chrome snippets and store the result in localStorage or just export it to the console in whatever order I wish and then paste it into a spreadsheet because it's easier to do when you have the DOM live in the browser.